# Relation or difference between mag, mögen and gern

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

I am new to German and I am confused when to use *mag, mögen* and *gern* in a sentence. So please help me to clarify my doubt, as these words have similiar meaning in English and uses in a sentence.

Comment: Could you please add the "similar meanings in English" you mentioned?

Comment: I assume you mean 'mögen' instead of 'morgen'? Because 'morgen' means tomorrow and this has nothing to do with the other two words.

Comment: @tallistroan correct, and I wish this question become more specific as to when it is confusing other than shown in the dictionary..

Comment: You should add the sentence to your question. This would make your problem clearer.

Comment: Iʼve changed _morgen_, but this question still needs edits by its original author.

Answer (score 2):

### mag

This is a conjugated form of the verb *mögen*. It is the indicative in *Präsens* (similar to present tense) in active voice for 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> person singular.

The verb *mögen* as full verb is *to like* in English:

> Ich *mag* dich.
>   I *like* you.
>
> Er *mag* schnelle Autos.
>   He *likes* fast cars.

But there is a second *mögen* which is a modal verb that has to used with the infinite form of another verb. In English you often translate is as *may* or *want to*:

> Das *mag* ja *sein*, aber er ist eben dein Chef.
>   That *may be* true, but he is your boss.
>
> Heinz *mag* sich *anstrengen* so viel er will, aber er wird nie an Martin herankommen.
>   Heinz *may try* as hard as he likes, but he will never get close to Martin.
>
> Ich *mag* heute nicht ins Kino *gehen*.
>   I do not *want to go* to the movies today.

Other grammatical forms of *mögen*:

> Ich *mag* Katzen. = I like cats.
>   Du *magst* Katzen. = You like cats.
>   Er *mag* Katzen. = He likes cats. (same for Sie=she and Es=it)
>   Wir *mögen* Katzen = We like cats.
>   Ihr *mögt* Katzen = You like cats.
>   Sie *mögen* Katzen = They like cats.

Some other tenses:

> Ich *mochte* Katzen. = I liked cats.
>   Ich *habe* Katzen *gemocht.* = I did like cats.
>   Ich *werde* Katzen *mögen.* = I will like cats.

You often use *mögen* in *Konjunktiv II* as modal verb to express a wish:

> Ich *möchte* heute Abend ins Theater *gehen*.
>   I *want to go* to the theater today evening.

---

### morgen

I guess you mixed this up with *mögen* which I explained above. (*Mögen* is the infinitive form of *mag*.) But anyway. You asked for *morgen*, so here is the answer:

The adverb *morgen* is in English: *tomorrow*. So it has absolutely no similarity with *mag* and *gern*:

> Ich fahre *morgen* zu meiner Schwester.
>   I'll drive to my sister *tomorrow.*

Note that there also is the noun *der Morgen* which is *the morning*.

---

### gern

This is an adverb. The English translation is *willingly* or *gladly*, but you often use different constructions to express the meaning that is expressed with a German sentence containing *gern*:

> Ich spiele *gern* Schach.
>   *Literal translation:* I play chess *gladly*.
>   *Better English:* I like to play chess.

The Literal German translation of the "better English" sentence is:

> Ich liebe es, Schach zu spielen.

You often find translations from English into German that contain lots of *"zu + infinitive"* phrases. This is correct, but not really perfect German. German native speaker prefer the other construction.

Another meaning of *gern* is *often*:

> Meine Mutter vergisst *gern* ihr Handy zuhause.
>   My mother *often* forgets her mobile phone at home.

Third meaning: *jemanden gern haben* means *to like somebody.*

> Ich habe dich *gern.*
>   I *like* you.

Comment: You should probably mention the relevant combinations, i.e. _mag gern(e)_ and _möchte gern(e)_.